# Different definitions of $L^p$ space (Sobolev spaces, and Hölder spaces) on non-compact manifolds.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

For a **non-manifold** $M$, we have the following different definitions of $L^p$ spaces:

$$
   L^p(M)=\left\{ \text{$u$ is locally integrable}: 
   \|u\|_p=\left(\int_M |u|^q\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}<\infty\right\}
$$

Or, let $(B_i)$ be an open cover of $M$
where each $(B_i,\phi_i)$ is a coordinate ball,
and let $(\rho_i)$ be a partition of unity subordinate to $(B_i)$; then we define $L^p$ space as
$$
L^p(M)=\left\{ \text{$u$ is locally integrable}: 
   \|u\|_p'=\sum_i \left\|\left(\rho_i u\right)\circ\phi_i^{-1}\right\|_{p}<\infty \right\}.
$$

My question is:

> Do these two definitions coincide?

**My attempt**

If $M$ is compact, it's easy to see that the norms are equivalent, and hence the two definitions are equivalent. In fact, we have
$$
  N\left(\int_M |u|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}\ge \sum_{i=1}^N\left(\int_M \left|\rho_i u\right|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p},
$$
$$  \left(\int_M |u|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
  =\left(\int_M \Big|\sum_{i=1}^N\rho_i u\Big|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
  \le\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\int_M \left|\rho_i u\right|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
  \le\,\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\int_M \left|\rho_i u\right|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}
 $$
where the last inequality follows from $p\ge 1$.

For the non-compact cases, such $N$ might be infinity, so the above proof fails.
However, we can find a countale open cover $(B_i)$ consisting of coordinate balls **and a constant $C$ such that each point $p\in M$ admits a neighborhood $U_p$ that intersects at most $C$ sets in the collection.** Does this help us to show that the two definitions are equivalent?

*Here is a sketch for the existence of such $(B_i)$ and $C$:*

We equip $M$ with a metric $g$ such that $\mathrm{Ric}\ge c(n)$ where $c(n)$ is a constant depending on the dimension. Choose a maximal collection $(B_1(x_i))$ consisting of geodesic balls of radius $1$ such that $B_1(x_i)\cap B_1(x_j)=\emptyset$ if $i\ne j$. Then $(B_3(x_i))$ forms an open cover of $M$.
By Bishop-Gromov volume comparison theorem, such $C$ exists.

**Added**

We can put forward the same question for Sobolev spaces and Hölder spaces.
Any helps will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is $\mu$? Is $\mu$ is a measure on $M$?

Comment: @Mason Yes, $\int_M f\,d\mu=\int_M f\,d\mathrm{vol}$, where $d\mathrm{vol}$ is the volume form.

Comment: If you have a measure already, then why not use $L^p(M, \mu)$? E.g. if $M$ has a metric tensor, then you get a volume measure from that. Is that what you call $\mu$?

Comment: @Mason Yes, it is exactly. But from the viewpoint of geometry, people want to learn the function spaces by the partion of unity and summing the local terms which can be considered as on $\mathbb R^n$. So I want to figure out the difference between these two definitions.

Comment: The integral $\int_{M}f\,dvol$ can be computed by partition of unity and summing terms since $dvol$ is a differential form.

Comment: @Mason The point is that, I am wondering whether these two **norms** are equivalent.